# Help identifying urban fantasy book from first chapter memory (sorcerer, phony medium)

Tags: story-identification

At some point in the past, I think Kindle must have done one of those "First chapter" things and I read the first chapter of a book. Looking back now, I remember it, but I can't for the life of me find out what it was despite several hours googling various combinations of the bits I remember.

So, what I do remember? Modern day setting Urban Fantasy, and the sample chapter read in the last year or so.

First chapter was the Sorcerer (described as I think, not Wizard) attending a psychic evening by a phony medium because he likes debunking them - Waiting for her to say a "Barnum Statement" that could apply to everyone, then calling her out on stage, using a bit of magic, then magically duplicating his business card to dish out to the crowd and leaving.  All a way to advertise himself if people needed his services.

I think (Assuming I'm not mixing books), that he also mentioned a quirk where he got his power by stealing it from other Sorcerers, but would only steal it from bad guys.

Don't have much beyond that I'm afraid as it was just the sample chapter.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: I assume that https://www.librarything.com/topic/290739 is also you. :) We just like to note cross-posting so that no one gets excited and then disappointed, and so we can tie it back if someone finds the answer.

Comment: Thank you for keeping up with your question, adding additional details. I think you're pretty good, but there are a few more prompts at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably Sean Stone's *[Warlock for Hire](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/30308683-warlock-for-hire)*, first book of his *Arcane Inc.* series.

[image: Book cover of *Warlock for Hire]

> Meet Eddie Lancaster. That's me. I'm annoying, rude and I'm not sorry. I'm also a warlock. Not just any warlock. I'm a warlock for hire. Need magical assistance? I'm your guy. Whatever you need: spell, cures or potion, I can provide. For a price.
>
> My life gets tad more difficult when one particular customer comes knocking. She’s sexy, mysterious and incredibly dangerous. I should have turned her away but I just can’t resist a good mystery. So I poked my nose where it doesn’t belong and landed myself in trouble with a malignant seer. I have to do as he says or people are going to die. I’m not really known for cooperation so I just have to find a way to kill him before he kills the people I care about.

From the first chapter:

> So, who am I? Eddie Lancaster, director of Arcane Incorporated. Sounds mysterious and important, eh? That’s the point. And no, it’s not really a company, more of a one man show, but Arcane Inc. just has a better ring to it. Don’t you think? I’m basically a warlock for hire. Need something supernatural? Come to me. Now, I know what you’re thinking. Warlocks are bad, right? Wrong. Well no, they are bad. Most anyway. But I’m a different kind of warlock. A unique kind of warlock. A one-of-a-kind kind of warlock. I’m what you’d call a natural warlock. Ordinary warlocks are sorcerers who steal magic from other sorcerers. In order to steal said magic, they must kill said sorcerer. So, you can understand why warlocks are naturally associated with badness. I, however, do not kill. I was born with the ability to just take power from a sorcerer. No killing, no hurting. Just a clean old swipe. I don’t just go around swiping power either, that would also be wrong. Plus, it’s a little harder than a simple swipe. I only take it with consent. Except with bad people, evil people. If we cross paths I take their magic. For my own protection. You’re probably wondering now, when does somebody give me consent to take their magic? Well I could tell you, but I’ll be able to show you, if you wait until later.

Found with a search for *kindle fantasy novel wizard scam "business cards"*

Comment: You sir, are a legend - I tried so many damn variations on google searches... wonder if "kindle" made the difference as I never tried adding that.  Still annoys me which book that first chapter was appended to the end of as a sample.  Thanks!

Comment: @Reoryn: No worries. Thank you for coming back to accept it. :) I have found that adding "kindle" to the search when I think it's an ebook has been helpful. But, like most searches, it sometimes works and sometimes does not. Initially, I searched using "barnum statement" and "cold reading" and that didn't help at all. It was "business cards" that turned the tide, oddly enough, as a Goodreads review mentioned them.

Comment: Ah, and the first chapter does include both mention of a "Barnum statement" and the multiplying business cards. :-P Today is my last day of Kindle Unlimited.

Comment: I tried business cards several times too, but didn't get anywhere - i think the Kindle addition to that might have done it as I was getting too many random results.  The book might be terrible, but I feel I now have to read it regardless :D

You're welcome, and thanks again.